# kml file coordinates with altitude 0

Tags: kml, google-earth, altitude

I've draw a path in Google Earth and then tried to export it as a kml file. I've done the trick with copy paste and it worked. I could create a kml file with all coordinates on it, unfortunately the altitude of each is coordinates is always set to 0. I have tried every altitude modes, from absolute, relativeToGround, relativeToSeaFloor, clampToGround and clampToSeaFloor and still got 0 on each.

```
             <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <gx:altitudeMode>clampToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>
-0.03577057649673097,43.76757757633825,0 
-0.03574088790371616,43.76768808940936,0 
-0.03575433162010139,43.7677802270933,0 
-0.03582561152308676,43.76788089757672,0 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
```

The strange is, the elevation profile of the path on Google Earth is correct. I must do something wrong when i export to the kml file.

Can anyone tell me, how i can export the path that i have draw with the correct altitude values to a kml file ?

Comment: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working absolutely correct. You specify 'clampto(sea)floor' - so get a line that hugs terrain.

If you want heights for your file - you have to get it from another source.

I made a tool for it: http://www.nearby.org.uk/elevation-kml.php